# var vs let in JS: scoping in function callback

Tags: javascript, callback, var, let, scoping

The following code snippet outputs `10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10`

```
var fs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fs.push(function() {return i;})
}

console.log(fs.map(function(f) {return f()}).join())
```

Whereas if `var` in for loop is changed to `let` as below, the output is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

Can someone please help understand this scoping issue and the mysterious way in which JS works?

Comment: there are already thousands of explanations out there...

Comment: Read about: **closures** and **scoping**.

Comment: If you use `var` it will be as if you declare the variable before the `for` loop (thus all iteration share a reference to the same variable and when that variable get incremented, the functions in the array try to access the value of that variable, since they all have a reference to the same one, they print the same value). When using `let`, each iteration creates a new variable, thus each function has a reference to its own version of the variable.